# how to get android spellchecker framework working

Tags: java, android, spell-checking

I have tried getting the android spelling checker working

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html

However cannot understand how to. The hello spellchecker will load up a blank activity whilst the service example does nothing.

They are accessible through the sdk examples.

Does anyone know how to use them?

Comment: @cbrulak just tried accessing them and running them however don't quite get how they are men't to work. Cannot seem to do anything

Comment: The srivce exaple will run only if you will change your device spell checker to "sample spell checker". Go to settings->language and input->spell checker and select "sample spell checker". Now run the hello spell checker activity - it will use the sample service as spell checker.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you a TextView of the words they have entered in the HelloSpellChecker and a few suggestions.
FIRST install the SampleSpellCheckerService and then install the HelloSpellChecker app. If it doesnt work the first time try making a minor change to the HelloSpellCheckerActivity(insert a comment or a clank space) and run it again, it works.

Comment: Source code here: https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SpellChecker